# cygwin/x no image from remote host

Tags: linux, ssh, linux-mint, cygwin, x11-forwarding

I installed and started cygwin x server and everything seems working. Log from `startxwin`:

```
$ startxwin

Could not load crashreporter dll
Welcome to the XWin X Server
Vendor: The Cygwin/X Project
Release: 1.17.1.0
OS: CYGWIN_NT-6.1 mykhn 2.0.4(0.287/5/3) 2015-06-09 12:22 x86_64
OS: Windows 7 Service Pack 1 [Windows NT 6.1 build 7601] (Win64)
Package: version 1.17.1-5 built 2015-06-02

XWin was started with the following command line:

/usr/bin/XWin :0 -multiwindow -auth
 /home/Mykhailo_Nesterenko/.serverauth.10908

Could not load crashreporter dll
(II) xorg.conf is not supported
(II) See http://x.cygwin.com/docs/faq/cygwin-x-faq.html for more information
LoadPreferences: /home/Mykhailo_Nesterenko/.XWinrc not found
LoadPreferences: Loading /etc/X11/system.XWinrc
LoadPreferences: Done parsing the configuration file...
winDetectSupportedEngines - DirectDraw4 installed, allowing ShadowDDNL
winDetectSupportedEngines - Returning, supported engines 00000005
winSetEngine - Multi Window or Rootless => ShadowGDI
winScreenInit - Using Windows display depth of 32 bits per pixel
winAllocateFBShadowGDI - Creating DIB with width: 3600 height: 1080 depth: 32
winFinishScreenInitFB - Masks: 00ff0000 0000ff00 000000ff
winInitVisualsShadowGDI - Masks 00ff0000 0000ff00 000000ff BPRGB 8 d 24 bpp 32
setlocale failed.
MIT-SHM extension disabled due to lack of kernel support
XFree86-Bigfont extension local-client optimization disabled due to lack of shar                                                                                                                                  ed memory support in the kernel
glWinSelectGLimplementation: Loaded 'cygnativeGLthunk.dll'
(II) AIGLX: Testing pixelFormatIndex 1
GL_VERSION:     3.3.0 - Build 8.15.10.2712
GL_VENDOR:      Intel
GL_RENDERER:    Intel(R) HD Graphics 4000
(II) AIGLX: enabled GLX_SGI_make_current_read
(II) AIGLX: enabled GLX_MESA_copy_sub_buffer
(II) AIGLX: enabled GLX_SGI_swap_control and GLX_MESA_swap_control
(II) AIGLX: enabled GLX_SGIX_pbuffer
(II) AIGLX: enabled GLX_ARB_multisample and GLX_SGIS_multisample
(II) 66 pixel formats reported by wglGetPixelFormatAttribivARB
(II) AIGLX: Set GLX version to 1.4
(II) 21 fbConfigs
(II) ignored pixel formats: 0 not OpenGL, 6 RBGA float, 3 RGBA unsigned float, 0                                                                                                                                   unknown pixel type, 36 unaccelerated
(II) GLX: Initialized Win32 native WGL GL provider for screen 0
winPointerWarpCursor - Discarding first warp: 1800 540
(--) 16 mouse buttons found
(--) Setting autorepeat to delay=500, rate=31
(--) Windows keyboard layout: "00000409" (00000409) "US", type 4
(--) Found matching XKB configuration "English (USA)"
(--) Model = "pc105" Layout = "us" Variant = "none" Options = "none"
Rules = "base" Model = "pc105" Layout = "us" Variant = "none" Options = "none"
winMultiWindowXMsgProc - DISPLAY=:0.0
winInitMultiWindowWM - DISPLAY=:0.0
winProcEstablishConnection - winInitClipboard returned.
winClipboardThreadProc - DISPLAY=:0.0
OS maintains clipboard viewer chain: yes
winMultiWindowXMsgProc - XOpenDisplay () returned and successfully opened the di                                                                                                                                  splay.
winInitMultiWindowWM - XOpenDisplay () returned and successfully opened the disp                                                                                                                                  lay.
winClipboardProc - XOpenDisplay () returned and successfully opened the display.
winMultiWindowXMsgProcErrorHandler - ERROR: BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
winMultiWindowXMsgProcErrorHandler - ERROR: BadWindow (invalid Window parameter)
winMultiWindowXMsgProcErrorHandler - ERROR: BadWindow (invalid Window parameter)
winMultiWindowXMsgProcErrorHandler - ERROR: BadWindow (invalid Window parameter)
winMultiWindowXMsgProcErrorHandler - ERROR: BadWindow (invalid Window parameter)
winMultiWindowXMsgProcErrorHandler - ERROR: BadWindow (invalid Window parameter)
winMultiWindowXMsgProcErrorHandler - ERROR: BadWindow (invalid Window parameter)
```

Then I connect to remote linux host and export display variable:

```
ssh -Y some_host
export DISPLAY=:0.0
```

When I try to run `xclock` everything seems to work (there is no error on remote host), but nothing appears locally:

```
$ xclock &
[1] 28392
```

What could be wrong?

**UPD**
it appeared that xclock attached to remote x server, not my local. Its window was visible when I logged physically to remote computer (not via ssh).

Answer (score 1):

Oh, all I needed to do is not to set `DISPLAY` property. It is correctly set in `xterm` so I just connected to remote host and started xclock and that correctly worked!